# What is easiest way to defer JS Scripts for Laravel Website?

Tags: laravel-5, cpanel, google-pagespeed

I have implement Cache tool on my cPanel server and configured it but i am getting Defer Parsing JavaScript warning in gtmetrix and google pagespeed

Answer (score 0):

1) Put any js script reference to footer.
2) 
a) Add Async attribute to the script.

```
<script async src="script.js"></script>
```

b) You can also test it with Defer attribute.

```
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
```

3) Optionally if possible try to combine the js files, this will give better result in PageSpeed in most cases.